# How can I find out information about a service?

Tags: mysql, services, nmap

```
$ nmap -p0-65535 192.168.0.142

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-10 17:53 EDT
Nmap scan report for ocean (192.168.0.142)
Host is up (0.000031s latency).
Not shown: 65531 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
3306/tcp  open  mysql
33060/tcp open  mysqlx

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.06 seconds
```

What is service `mysqlx`?

Why is it not mapped in `/etc/services`?

```
$ cat /etc/services  |  grep mysql
mysql       3306/tcp
mysql       3306/udp
mysql-proxy 6446/tcp            # MySQL Proxy
mysql-proxy 6446/udp
```

Why is it not part of the command for the process?

```
$ ps -A | grep mysqlx
```

Is it possible that `nmap` can report misleading information? Do you find out the services running on the local machine not by `nmap`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mysqlx` service on port 33060 is the [MySQL X DevAPI service](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/database-connection-example.html).

`nmap` does not use `/etc/services`, it uses [its own database of services](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/nmap-services).

Note that *anything* listening on port 33060 will be reported as the `mysqlx` service, and that the name of a service does not necessarily have to be part of the name of the command providing the service (both `exim` and `postfix` may provide an `smtp` service, for example).

To see what's listening on port 33060 on the local machine, you may use, on a Linux system,

```
sudo lsof -i :33060
```

or

```
sudo fuser -v 33060/tcp
```

Comment: Thanks. does `fuser 33060/tcp` works the same as `sudo lsof -i :33060`?

Comment: @Tim Not quite, I _think_ you would need `sudo fuser -v 33060/tcp` to get any interesting information.

Comment: Thanks. I have this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507452/why-cant-lsof-report-some-open-ports-information, when reading your reply